# What is the inverse of date.toordinal() in python?

Tags: python, date

In python, a `date`object can be converted in the proleptic Gregorian ordinal this way:

```
d=datetime.date(year=2010, month=3, day=1)
d.toordinal()
```

but what is the reverse operation?

Comment: Err.... [date.fromordinal](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromordinal) ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The opposite is [date.fromordinal](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromordinal)

> **classmethod date.fromordinal(ordinal)**
>
> Return the date corresponding to the proleptic Gregorian ordinal,
>   where  January 1 of year 1 has ordinal 1. ValueError is raised unless
>   1 <= ordinal <= date.max.toordinal(). For any date d,
>   date.fromordinal(d.toordinal()) == d.

Answer (score 5):

It's `date.fromordial()` as Jon wrote in the comments.

or `datetime.fromordinal()`

You can read more about it in the [date= documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromordinal)

and for [datetime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromordinal)

From the docs:

> `classmethod` `date.fromordinal(ordinal)`
>
> Return the date corresponding
>   to the proleptic Gregorian ordinal, where January 1 of year 1 has
>   ordinal 1. `ValueError` is raised unless `1 <= ordinal <=
>   date.max.toordinal()`.
>
> For any date `d`, `date.fromordinal(d.toordinal())
>   == d.`

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623156/how-to-convert-the-integer-date-format-into-yyyymmdd).

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> dt = datetime.fromordinal(733828)
```