# Convert date to ordinal python?

Tags: python, datetime

I want to convert
2010-03-01 to 733832

I just found this toordinal code

```
d=datetime.date(year=2010, month=3, day=1)
d.toordinal()
```

from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16542074/what-is-the-inverse-of-date-toordinal-in-python)

But i want something more like

```
d=datetime.date('2010-03-01')
d.toordinal()
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Look at [strptime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You'll need to use [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) on the date string, specifying the format, then you can call the `toordinal` method of the `date` object:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime as dt
>>> d = dt.strptime('2010-03-01', '%Y-%m-%d').date()
>>> d
datetime.date(2010, 3, 1)
>>> d.toordinal()
733832
```

The call to the `date` method in this case is redundant, and is only kept for making the object consistent as a `date` object instead of a `datetime` object.

If you're looking to handle more date string formats, [Python's strftime directives](http://strftime.org/) is one good reference you want to check out.

Comment: As a note, from Python 3.7 onwards you can also use `datetime.fromisoformat()` for simple ISO dates.

Answer (score 5):

like this:

```
datetime.strptime("2016-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d").toordinal()
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to firstly convert the time string to `datetime` object using [`strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime). Then call `.toordinal()` on the `datetime` object

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> date = datetime.strptime('2010-03-01', '%Y-%M-%d')
>>> date.toordinal()
733773
```

It is even better to create a function to achieve this as:

```
def convert_date_to_ordinal(date):
    return datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%M-%d').toordinal()

convert_date_to_ordinal('2010-03-01')
#returns: 733773
```