# Xarray datetime to ordinal

Tags: pandas, datetime, python-xarray, ordinal

In pandas there is a `toordinal` function to convert the datetime to ordinal, such as:[Convert date to ordinal python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39846918/convert-date-to-ordinal-python) or [Pandas datetime column to ordinal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20576618/pandas-datetime-column-to-ordinal). I have an xarray dataarray with time coordinate that I want to convert it to ordinal. Is there similar panda's `toordinal` to do it in xarray?
sample:

```
Coordinates:
time
array(['2019-07-31T10:00:00.000000000', '2019-07-31T10:15:00.000000000',
       '2019-07-31T10:30:00.000000000', '2019-07-31T10:45:00.000000000',
       '2019-07-31T11:00:00.000000000', '2019-07-31T11:15:00.000000000',
       '2019-07-31T11:30:00.000000000', '2019-07-31T11:45:00.000000000',
       '2019-07-31T12:00:00.000000000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a `xarray`-native way to do it.

But, you can work around it by converting the time values to `datetime` objects, on which you can then use `toordinal`:

```py
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr

ds = xr.tutorial.open_dataset("air_temperature")
time_ordinal = [pd.to_datetime(x).toordinal() for x in ds.time.values]

print(time_ordinal[:5])
# [734869, 734869, 734869, 734869, 734870]
```