# Convert date from integer to date format

Tags: python, pyspark, aws-glue

I have a column 'start_date' which is an integer 37823. This happened when I used xlrd library to convert xlsx to csv. Hence '2003/07/21' got converted to 37823.

I have gone through xlrd documentation and I understand there are several ways to convert it to date. However, I need to convert this to date format using PySpark in AWS Glue ETL jobs. Any suggestions?

I tried using to_date, date_format functions, but nothing worked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I read a date in Excel format in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108428/how-do-i-read-a-date-in-excel-format-in-python)

Comment: Dylan - I guess its not. As I am not looking to convert it to date format during xlsx to csv conversion. I need to convert it later in the data pipeline. Is that possible?

Comment: Isn't this going to work for you -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623156/how-to-convert-the-integer-date-format-into-yyyymmdd ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert the integer date format into YYYYMMDD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623156/how-to-convert-the-integer-date-format-into-yyyymmdd)

Comment: @Dawid_Sielski - I used the same function like this :df = df.withColumn('hire date', datetime.fromordinal(df['hire date']).strftime('%Y%m%d'))
TypeError: an integer is required

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to finally resolve this issue.

Using UDF:

```
def convert_date(x):
    mDt = datetime.datetime(1899, 12, 30)
    dlt = mDt + datetime.timedelta(days=x)
    return dlt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

convert_date_udf = udf(lambda z: convert_date(z), StringType())
df = df.withColumn('hire date', convert_date_udf('hire date').alias('hire date new'))
```

Without using UDF:

```
df = df.withColumn('hire date', F.expr("date_add(to_date('1899-12-30'), cast(`hire date` as int))").cast(StringType())
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that there are more elegant ways to done this but this is what I have come up with for now.

```
from datetime import date
df.hire_date = df.hire_date.apply(date.fromordinal) # this will give you date in dash format
df.hire_date = df.hire_date.apply(lambda x: str(x).replace('-', '/')) # this will simply replace dash with slash
```

Hope that this works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like **12/30/1899 + 37823 days = 2003/07/21**

You can use this [date_add](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.date_add) function below instead of UDF or python functions. UDFs are supposed to be a little slower than pyspark functions.

```
weird_date = 37823
df = spark.createDataFrame([('1899-12-30',)], ['dt'])
df.select(date_add(df.dt, weird_date).alias('converted_date')).collect()
```

Comment: Thanks Lucifer. I tried something like this: df2 = spark.createDataFrame([('1899-12-30',)], ['dt'])
df = df.select(date_add(df2.dt, df['hire date']).alias('converted_date')).collect()
print df.head()           Got this error: TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable

Comment: I think it's because you used "df" before you declared it.

Comment: Well I keep getting the error : Method date_add([class org.apache.spark.sql.Column, class java.lang.String]) does not exist. This is mycode: from pyspark.sql import functions as f df2 = spark.createDataFrame([('1899-12-30',)], ['dt'])
df = df.select(f.date_add(df2.dt, 'hire date').alias('hire date'))

Comment: The date_add function takes (column, integer). You're trying to put (column, string).

Comment: The 'hire date' column is of IntegerType. However, since it has a space, I am not able to use it without '' and when I use it with '', it is interpreted as string.

Comment: For columns with space, I had to use backticks (`) instead of single quotes ('). That worked for me.