# Get event.xdata on a plot_date graphon a canvas

Tags: python, matplotlib, events

I load a csv in a pandas dataframe (one column is full of datime values):

```
def edit(filename):
    df = pd.read_csv ( filename, sep=';',decimal=',', skiprows=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20], error_bad_lines=False )

    df = df[['TimeString','VarValue']]


    df['TimeString'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['TimeString'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
    df['VarValue'] = pd.to_numeric(df['VarValue'])

    return df
```

I draw a plot with plot_date:

```
def plotting(self, df):
    self.axes.grid(True)
    self.axes.plot_date(df['TimeString'], df['VarValue'],'-',label='MACD_14_21')
    self.axes.legend(loc='upper left')
    self.canvas.draw()
```

[image]

Now I would like to use the function:

```
def onMouseMove(self, event):
    print(event.xdata, event.ydata)

cid = self.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', self.onMouseMove)
```

What I get is:

```
737235.953598 91.53
```

So The event.ydata works fine, but the event.xdata instead of give me a datetime values is giving me a unknown float64.
But in the meanwhile the GUI inferface is going to get the correct X data value:

[image]

So, How can I get the right datetime value? Or how can I convert the float value in a datetime value?

Thank you so much for your help

Luca

PS: all the tutorials shown the possibility to use the normal plot with datetime values too  but when I use it with so many data (>20k) the plotting is very slow.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2623191/11305111) might help.  otherwise, if you could include all the code to reproduce that would be helpful.

Comment: Yeah, this was a good starting point to start to play with data: days and hours. Thanks!